# Eclipse PHP Photon Xdebug not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug

I've changed my environment.

I was using XAMPP before and it was working perfectly. But when I changed to pure PHP and Apache 2 my Eclipse Photon stopped recognizing my Xdebug installation.

[image]

But it's installed. And it's not working.

My `phpinfo()` is showing to me:

```
This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
   with Zend OPcache v7.1.22-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
   with Xdebug v2.6.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
```

In my php.ini (/etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini) I added this information:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/tmp"
```

This file exists `/usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so`

What can be wrong?

Comment: Your new PHP may be using different php.ini config file: one for Apache and one for CLI. Double check what config file is used.

Comment: 1) How did you tested `phpinfo()`, make sure you do that via apache response. You should see [this table](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Debugging_using_XDebug#Configuration). 2) Double check your [eclipse setup](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Debugging_using_XDebug).